# SPItemEvent: abort the event from the EventHandler

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How can I abort an item even (in my case, ItemDeleting) so that it doesn'r get executed? I want the deletion not to take place if certain conditions are matched and do it silently for the use (no messages, no exceptions). Thanks

EDIT:
SP 2010

Comment: Please specify SharPoint version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties) {
    properties.Cancel = true;
    properties.ErrorMessage = "Something went wrong!";
}
```

If you cancel it though, it will be reported back to the user, nothing you can do about that.

**UPDATE**

For use the Status property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventpropertiesbase.status.aspx

```
public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties) {
    properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelNoError;
}
```

Comment: Note that SPEventPropertiesBase.Cancel is deprecated in SP 2010. In the first example, use properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError instead of properties.Cancel = true. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventpropertiesbase.cancel.aspx